# Optimizing SQL Query speed

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization, firebird

I am trying to optimize my SQL query below as I am using a very old RDMS called firebird. I tried rearranging the items in my where clause and removing the order by statement but the query still seems to take forever to run. Unfortunately firebird doesn't support Explain Execution Plan Functionalities and therefore I cannot identify the code that is holding up the query.

```
select T.veh_reg_no,T.CON_NO, sum(T.pos_gpsunlock) as SUM_GPS_UNLOCK,
count(T.pos_gpsunlock) as SUM_REPORTS, contract.con_name
from
(
    select veh_reg_no,CON_NO,
         case when pos_gpsunlock = upper('T') then 1 else 0 end as pos_gpsunlock 
    from vehpos
    where veh_reg_no in
        ( select regno 
          from fleetvehicle 
          where fleetno in (97)
        )        --DS5
        and pos_timestamp > '2022-07-01'
        and pos_timestamp < '2022-08-01'
) T
join contract  on T.con_no = contract.con_no
group by T.veh_reg_no, T.con_no,contract.con_name
order by SUM_GPS_UNLOCK desc;
```

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using `in` instead of a `join` "could" be causing you some slower speed, do you have any indexes on your tables?

Comment: for performace question is a lot of information needed, see the subsection here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question and edit your question

Comment: probably want `>=` for the first `pos_timestamp` condition

Comment: Firebird does have functionality to show an execution plan, however it requires API access (most access components or drivers surface it in some way), or you can get it through isql ([`set plan`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-plan) or - Firebird 3.0 and higher - [`set explain`](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-explain) for a more detailed plan). In short, shows us the plan or explained plan of the query. What is the DDL of the tables? What indexes exist?

Comment: Also, which Firebird version are you using? The fact you say _"a very old RDMS called firebird"_ suggests you're using an old version, as Firebird is still actively developed.

Comment: Also, as a starting point, using `IN` with a select can perform badly. You'd better solve that with a correlated `EXISTS` or maybe an `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd either comment out some of the sub-queries or remove a join or aggregation and see if that improves it. Once you find the offending code maybe you can move it or re-write it. I know nothing of Firebird but I'd approach that query with the below code, wrapping the aggregation outside of the joins and removing the "Where in" clause.

If nothing works can you create an aggregation table or pre-filtered table and use that?

```
select
x.*
,sum(case when x.pos_gpsunlock = upper('T') then 1 else 0 end) as SUM_GPS_UNLOCK
,count(*) as SUM_REPORTS

FROM (
    select 
        a.veh_reg_no
        ,a.pos_gpsunlock
        ,a.CON_NO
        ,c.con_name
    FROM vehpos a
    JOIN fleetvehicle b on a.veg_reg_no = b.reg_no and b.fleetno = 97 and b.pos_timestamp between '222-07-01' and '2022-08-01'
    JOIN contract c on a.con_no = contract.con_no 
    ) x
Group By....
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help by converting subqueries to joins and reducing nesting. Also an `=` instead of `IN()` operation.

```
select vp.veh_reg_no,vp.con_no,c.con_name,
     count(*) as SUM_REPORTS,
     sum(case when pos_gpsunlock = upper('T') then 1 else 0 end) as SUM_GPS_UNLOCK
from vehpos vp
inner join fleetvehicle fv on fv.fleetno = 97 and fv.regno = vp.veh_reg_no
inner join contract c on  vp.con_no = c.con_no
where vp.pos_timestamp >= '2022-07-01'
    and vp.pos_timestamp < '2022-08-01'
group by vp.veh_reg_no, vp.con_no, c.con_name
```